# For an assignment I have to compare two dates use structures in C. I am not sure as to if my logic is wrong here

Tags: c, date, structure

First I compared the two dates and checked if the date is earlier or if it is the same. I am not sure as to if my logic is wrong here or what is. The printf statement does not seem to work that says date 1 is earlier or they are the same or date 1 is later.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct dates
{
    int month;
    int date;
    int year;
};

int compareDates(struct dates d1, struct dates d2)
{
    printf(d2.year);
    printf(d2.month);
    printf(d2.date);

    if(d2.year >= d1.year) // compares year
    {
        if(d2.month >= d1.month) // months
        {
            if(d2.date > d1.date) 
            {
                printf("date 1 is earlier\n"); 
                return - 1;  
            }
        }
    }

    else if(d1.year == d2.year && d1.month == d2.month && d1.date == d2.date) // if they are the same
    {
        printf("They are the same\n");

        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
       printf("D1 is later\n");
       return 1;
    }

}

int main()
{
    struct dates d1;
    struct dates d2;

    printf("Enter year 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &d1.year);

    printf("Enter month 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &d1.month);

    printf("Enter date 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &d1.date);

    printf("Enter year 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &d2.year);

    printf(" Enter month 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &d2.month);

    printf("Enter date 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &d2.date);

    int return_value = compareDates(d1,d2);
}
```

Comment: that was me just testing the code thank you

Comment: Niraj Patel, poor etiquette to delete the code after is the question was answered.  Recommend you roll back that deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> compared the two dates and checked if the date is earlier or if it is the same. I am not sure as to if my logic is wrong here or what is.

`printf(d2.year);` is certainly wrong.  Try `printf("%d\n":, d2.year);`

`if(d2.month >= d1.month)` only makes sense if `(d2.year == d1.year)`, not `(d2.year >= d1.year)`

Compare member by member.  Start with most significant.

```
int compareDates(struct dates d1, struct dates d2) {
  if (d1.year  != d2.year)  return d1.year  > d2.year  ? 1 : -1;
  if (d1.month != d2.month) return d1.month > d2.month ? 1 : -1;
  return (d1.date > d2.date) - (d1.date < d2.date);
}
```

---

Additional code needed if members are not in the primary range like `2019-11-15 < 2018-100-15`.

Comment: I have a real problem with teaching people things like `return (d1.date > d2.date) - (d1.date < d2.date)` - it's non-portable to other languages, unnecessary, and doesn't clearly show intent. That's pretty much the unholy trinity of bad practice :-)

Comment: @pax It is a common C idiom the shows intent.  Portable to other languages is an interesting and worthy goal.  Had the post been tagged `algorithm`, I could agree, yet the post is tagged C and C style idioms, prevail.  Rather than reduce languages to the least common denominator, Employing each languages strength is something I would recommend.

Comment: Employing that particular strength in a classwork assignment will almost certainly *lose* you marks for lack of clarity. I wouldn't even allow that to pass reviews in production code. But, on the assumption I may not convince you, I won't argue the point any more.

Comment: Interesting " I wouldn't even allow that to pass reviews in production code".  Such decisions belong more in group's coding standards than one individual.  IAC I use to code like `if (d2 < d1) return -1; else return d1 > d2;` or the like.  Yet pushes for symmetric time per path, and compiler recognition, suggest `(d1 > d2) - (d1 < d2)`.    Hmmm or is it a sub-conscious longing for  [Arithmetic IF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_IF)?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be quite a few cases<sup>(a)</sup> you don't catch in your compare-date function. I would suggest starting with the following pseudo-code:

```
def isGreater(date1, date2):
    # If year different, use that to decide.

    if date1.year > date2.year: return true
    if date1.year < date2.year: return false

    # Years are the same, if month different use that.

    if date1.month > date2.month: return true
    if date1.month < date2.month: return false

    # Years and months are the same, use day.

    if date1.day > date2.day: return true
    return false
```

That doesn't provide a *specific* solution but, since it's classwork, you should be doing that bit yourself (it'll make you a much better developer than just providing a ready-made solution). This is just to show you the approach.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Specifically, you only consider a date to be greater if both year and month are greater or equal and day is greater. That wouldn't catch the fact that `2019-01-30` is greater than `2018-12-01`.